# Struggling with underclocking/undervolting GPU to decrease temperature/load

Tags: windows-10, gpu, temperature, overclocking, undervolting

I am trying to limit GPU for an app (that always runs on 100% usage) because it runs too long and too hot for my ease-of-mind.

I thought undervolting or underclocking (with MSI afterburner) would help reduce the allowed load and temperatures. It's not working like I expected (this is also my first time doing this).

My expectation:

- If I undervolted the GPU, it could use a lower voltage when running
  the application (for example, 1700MHz and 750mV when undervolted,
  compared to 1700MHz and 850mV at stock).

In reality:

- When I tried to undervolt by adjusting the curve so
  that the frequencies at lower voltages are higher, the program just
  uses a same/similar voltage, and temperature remains around the same.
  And when I tried to underclock by applying a negative offset to the
  clock speed (which shifted the whole curve down), the program just
  starts using a higher voltage, and temperatures remain around the
  same.

[Picture of curve and load at stock settings. Usage is 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRfXn.png)

[Curve for underclocking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FysG.png)

[Curve for undervolting (???)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZvOc.png)

[Undervolting, second version. I assume the fact that the operating point isn't on the curve anymore means I've undervolted it too much here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlXtQ.png)

Am I misunderstanding the point of underclocking and undervolting, or am I doing it wrong? Or is there another way to achieve my goal?

Sorry for the dumb question. I tried to look into it on my own but I'm struggling!

I'm using an Inspiron 7577 laptop, with GTX 1060 Max-Q and Windows 10. I think the power limit, temperature limit, and fan speed settings are locked for this model. Haven't been able to find anyway to unlock them. I don't want to open up my machine to apply thermal paste, and I'm already using a cooling pad.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a Dell Inspiron 7577 laptop, with Nvidia GeForce GTX 1060 with [Max-Q Design](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/products/10series/laptops/max-q/) and Windows 10 Pro too.

I tried similar thing unsuccessfully. I do believe this card in this laptop is locked (for a reason).

I even asked a Dell technician over the phone, and he told me this, and I tend to believe him.

<sub>In my humble opinion, when fiddling around with a laptop, it could cause more harm than the good.</sub>

Comment: "Locked" as in the voltage-frequency curve is unchangeable? Or locked as in changing it has no use because the computer doesn't respond to it in the usual way?